# About Javascript Module Architecture (Class VS Object literal)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

```js
// Class style
class class_sample {
    constructor(){

    }
    get_something (key) {
        result = do_something (key);
        return result 
    }
}
let class_sample = new class_sample();
module.exports = class_sample;
```

```js
// Object literal style
let literal_sample = {
    get_something : () => {
         result = do_something (key);
         return result 
    }
}
module.exports = literal_sample;
```

```js
let class_sample = require("/class_sample");
let literal_sample = require("literal_sample");

class_sample.get_something(key);
literal_sample.get_something(key);
```

I found there is a two type to make a module. The first is using Class, the second is Object literal.
Which one has better performance to make module?(about resource use and speed)

Comment: `class` will provide better readability

Comment: This may help. https://www.debuggr.io/js-prototype-in-depth/ goes into detail the differences between function / object / class patterns.

Comment: There is no need to use a class if you are just creating a single instance of it and export it. Think of it this way: If you only want to have a single shelve, are you going to build it directly or are you going to build a shelve building machine first?